# How to avoid special characters in RSA algorithm using soap webservice?

Tags: c#, rsa

I am implementing encryption and decryption using RSA algorithm. I am invoking webservice methods and its returning special characters and images in response.how to assign normal characters for getting response?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<soap:Fault>
<faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
<faultstring>Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; The system cannot find the file specified.
</faultstring>
<detail />
</soap:Fault>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to have anything to do with RSA, seems there is a FileNotFountException thrown on the server somewhere.

Comment: Seems like the wrong log line, otherwise the question and response seem totally unrelated.